# How to watch mocha-webpack tests results in mocha-test-explorer VS Code Extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, mocha.js, vue-cli, test-explorer, mocha-webpack

I'm working on a just created Vue cli project with TypeScript and unit testing.

I Know that Vue cli tests uses [mocha-webpack](https://zinserjan.github.io/mocha-webpack/) to runt tests. And when I Type `mocha-webpack` on terminal, the tests runs ok.

But I would like to use an [mocha-test-explorer, a VS Code extension for mocha testing](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hbenl.vscode-mocha-test-adapter). For a better programming experience.

I Installed the extension and configured like this:

```
"mochaExplorer.files": "tests/**/*.ts",
"mochaExplorer.require": "ts-node/register"
```

But I'm still not able to see the tests. test-explorer shows the fallowing output:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { expect } from 'chai'
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

I know that is because mocha is not loading files through webpack.

**What should I do to see [mocha-webpack](https://zinserjan.github.io/mocha-webpack/) tests in the [mocha-test-explorer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hbenl.vscode-mocha-test-adapter) extension (or any other gui extension) for VSCode?**